# JavaScript hover function stays open until button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for a couple of info boxes I have created using HTML and CSS. Is it possible to have the hover div stay open until the close button is clicked? Is this possible to do in Vanilla JavaScript? I'm new to JavaScript so anything helps, cheers!

```css
.everything {
  text-align: center;
  height: 1000px;
}

.everything:hover {
  cursor: default;
}

.infobox-list {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
li,
ol,
form,
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.hr {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin-left: 9px;
  width: 210px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  color: #555;
  min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
  height: 535px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 0px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.ptext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.profile {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.performance {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.learning {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.team {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.smallicons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.profileclose {
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 535px;
  width: 310px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%;
  height: 188%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 555px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #6caf46;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  /* the image will now scale down as its parent gets smaller */
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">


  <div class="everything">
    <br style="line-height:35px;">
    <section class="info-boxes">
      <ul class="infobox-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="infobox">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/profile_i0evlz.png"></tr>
                <tr>
                  <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="shade">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>About Me</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resume</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Accountabilities
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <div class="profileclose">Close</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Learning-Icon_hqtc2k.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Plan</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training History</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Course Feedback</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Favourites
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="infobox">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Performance-Icon_ozaldt.png"></tr>
                <tr>
                  <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="shade">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Goals</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                    <td>
                      <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                      <hr class="hr">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                    <td>
                      <p>Development Plan</p>
                      <hr class="hr">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resources
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/team_nl2cwh.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Team</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Development</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Training</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Approvals
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?  You can listen for the close button click and hide or destroy the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long, but here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a6rjxq7/).

Basically, you want to define a couple of event handlers for the mouseenter (to open) and click (to close) events, then change your CSS to account for that.  I'll post and explain each bit in an update momentarily.

For open and close handling, you just add and remove the "hover" class (rather than use the pseudoclass):

```
function open(e){
  let li = e.target;
  li.classList.add('hover');
}

function close(e){
  const hoverable = e.target.closest('li.hover');
  hoverable.classList.remove('hover');
}
```

Then change your :hover pseudoclass in CSS to use .hover instead:

```
.info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The adding event handlers and such is straightforward:

```
const infoBoxListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.info-boxes li');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.profileclose');

infoBoxListItems.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', open);
});

closeButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', close);
});
```

My full example includes the polyfill for `closest()` but that's a straight copy from MDN, so you can read up on it there.

Comment: The hover function doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: Are you using a modern browser?  It works fine on Chrome:latest.  If you have a different one, you might have to polyfill for some of the things  I used to save typing.

Comment: I am using IE, but I would need this to work for Edge and possibly Safari as well. My main concern would be for it to work with IE.

Comment: Honestly, it's possible to do all of what I did in IE-compliant versions, but it's probably easier to just use Modernizer or Babel to polyfill for you unless you've got some hard limit from your client.  Added the cdn version of babel on the update: https://jsfiddle.net/3a6rjxq7/1/

Comment: Like I said, start off by including Modernizr or Babel.  It's possible to do it w/o using those, but a) I can't test it as I don't have IE to test for you, and b) it gets rid of a *lot* of bugs that IE brings to the table.

Comment: I might post a question to see if anyone can help me out, anyways thanks a million!